# MySql: showing the average of products added in every section, daily wise for any month

Tags: mysql, select, count, report, categories

I want to show the average of products added in every section(category), daily wise for any month can you help me in that ?

Section are cars,villas and general

```
-----------------------------------------------
Date             Cars    Villas   General
===============================================
01-01-2011       20%     10%      70%
-----------------------------------------------
02-01-2011       31%     9%       60%
-----------------------------------------------
.
.
.
-----------------------------------------------
31-01-2011       70%     19%       11%
===============================================
```

Comment: I successfully fetch list for one day, but i want for whole month, and in tabular format like in question.
SELECT count( `product`.`cateogry_id` ) / P.total * 100 AS PERCENTAGE, `product`.`cateogry_id` AS CATEGORY, P.total
FROM `product` , (

SELECT count( M.`product_id` ) AS total
FROM product M
WHERE M.`product_date_added`='2011-01-01'

) AS P
WHERE `product`.`product_date_added`='2011-01-01'
GROUP BY product.`cateogry_id`

Comment: This results as:

PERCENTAGE  CATEGORY  total
=====================================
58.4488  22   361
8.3102   23   361
16.6205  24   361

here 22 for cars, 23 for villas and 24 for General, categories are not stored in a separate table. so no need for join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index.html) and look up the `GROUP_BY` and `AVG` functions. :)

Comment: thank you for suggestion, i tried but could not calculate it.